# Fancy array access in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

In Python numpy it is possible to use arrays of indexes, as in (taken from the tutorial):

```
data = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
i = array( [ [0,1],         # indices for the first dim of data
             [1,2] ] )
j = array( [ [2,1],         # indices for the second dim
             [3,3] ] )
```

Now, the invocation

```
data[i,j]
```

returns the array

```
array([[ 2,  5],
       [ 7, 11]])
```

How can I get the same in Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have to use [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) which you'll get from the [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function like this:

```
ind = sub2ind(size(data), I,J)
```

example:

```
data =[ 0,  1,  2,  3
        4,  5,  6,  7
        8,  9, 10, 11]

i = [0,1;
     1,2];

j = [2,1;
     3,3]

ind = sub2ind(size(data), i+1,j+1);
data(ind)

ans =

     2     5
     7    11
```

notice that I went `i+1` and `j+1`, this is because unlike Python which starts indexing at `0`, Matlab starts indexing from `1`.

Comment: Thanks Dan, it really does the job. Not as beautiful as Python, but it works. I did not know about `sub2ind`.

Comment: @zeycus Matlab is designed this way for a reason though, if you could use the same syntax as Python for this you would be sacrificing on beautiful syntax elsewhere.